# Best way to Remove the domain from url

Tags: groovy

I have to remove the domain's url from this: http://www.espn.com/watch/?gameId=1234&league=nfl&lang=es&profile=sportscenter_v1

Do you know a better way to achieve that without using things like:

def example= decodeUrl.replace( "http://www.espn.com", "" )

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use java.net.URI class. If you create URI from url String, you will have access to all components of the address, line, path, query, scheme, host port etc.
https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/net/URI.html

```
URI uri = new URI("http://www.espn.com/watch/?gameId=1234&league=nfl&lang=es&profile=sportscenter_v1")
println uri.path +"?"+ uri.query
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, it lacks explanation. Please consider adding text to explain what it does, and why it answers the question posed.

Answer (score 0):

If your domain if always ".com"
then you could try the following

```
     def url = "http://www.espn.com/watch/?gameId=1234&league=nfl&lang=es&profile=sportscenter_v1"
     /*The split function will spit the give string with a given sub string and store the splitted result in array of parts so here we are picking the second part having index 1*/
     def splitedUrl = url.split(".com")[1]
     println splitedUrl
```

Answer (score 0):

You can write this so the domain does not matter.

So here we are using **pattern matching**

```
def uri ="http://www.espn.com/watch/?gameId=1234&league=nfl&lang=es&profile=sportscenter_v1"
def parameters= uri=~ "https?://.*?/(.*)"
log.info parameters[0][1]
```

As of now the pattern that is written it can take care for http and https as well

You may have to use **try catch** so in case only www.espn.com comes without any parameter to handle that situation

To cover all possible scenarios for url you may refer this [link](https://developer.chrome.com/apps/match_patterns)

Even though the answered shared by Yeugeniuss is the most logical but this is also one of the way to do it