# is it possible to create a regex to remove entire domain (without subdomain) with Kotlin/Java including (or not) ports?

Tags: java, regex, kotlin

I look in many posts for a possible answer but none of them seem to solve my problem

[How to remove some part of URL by regex?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19254720/how-to-remove-some-part-of-url-by-regex)

[Best way to Remove the domain from url](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51886613/best-way-to-remove-the-domain-from-url)

[Best way to Remove the domain from url](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51886613/best-way-to-remove-the-domain-from-url)

[In Java, how do I extract the domain of a URL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51634183/in-java-how-do-i-extract-the-domain-of-a-url)

I basically will have an URL I dont know how it is. Like:

```
https://somevalue.google.com/something
```

or

```
www.somevalue.google.com/something
```

or

```
somevalue.localhost:8080/something
```

I will basically need to get rid of the domain **ONLY** (and not of the subdomain) with the http(s), www, .com or :8080 but seems to be more difficult than expected.

I have tried with this regex

```
"^(http[s]?://www\\.|http[s]?://|www\\.)"
```

And I was able to remove http, https, and/or www

From then I thought would be easier to add multiple combinations like adding

```
[\w] or `[?:*]` but seems like is not getting a proper match.
```

I based myself on this doc http://zetcode.com/kotlin/regularexpressions/ that explains what is for each patter but no success.

Any idea what Im doing wrong?

I dont want to get ride of the subdomain either `somevalue`

so, from

```
https://somevalue.google.com/something...
```

Get something like

```
somevalue/something....
```

Comment: So in all your examples you want to get `/something` in the end?

Comment: yes, I need to get somevalue/something....

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In plain Java you could try the following regex: `(?i)(?:[a-z]+://)?(?:[^/]+)(/.*)?`

- the first `(?i)` will make it case-insensitive
- the second part (`(?:[a-z]+://)?`) will match an optional protocol in a non-capturing group
- the third part (`(?:[^/]+)`) will match anything up to the next slash, i.e. the domain and any optional port, also in a non-capturing group
- the last part (`(/.*)?`) will capture anything starting with a slash (if present) into a capturing group - that's the group you want to keep

Edit:

It seems I missed that you want to keep the subdomains as well. Try the following adjusted query:
 `(?i)^(?:[a-z]+://)?(?:www\.)?(.*?)(?:\.[^./]+){2}(/.*)?$`

Changes:

- I added `^...$` to match the entire string, which is needed for the next part
- right after the protocol part `(?:www\.)?` will match `www.` if that is present
- after that `(.*?)` will match the subdomain if present
- the domain part has been changed from `(?:[^/]+)` to `(?:\.[^./]+){2}` which now matches any sequence of a dot followed by anthing except a dot or a slash and that repeated 2 times. That would match `google.com`, `.google.com`, `google.com:1234` etc.

To get `somevalue/something...` from `https://www.somevalue.google.com:1234/something...` you'd then use the following code in Java:

```
String regex = "(?i)^(?:[a-z]+://)?(?:www\\.)?(.*?)(?:\\.[^./]+){2}(/.*)?$";
String replaced = "https://www.somevalue.google.com:1234/something...".replaceAll(regex, "$1$2");
```

Note that this might still not fit all your requirements (which we don't know exactly) so keep in mind that if they get more complex it might be better/easier to use parse the url properly.

Comment: unfortunately, when I use this I get my whole string removed :|

Comment: @jpganz18 well, you didn't state how exactly you use that expression. In Java you could do something like this: `String replaced = original.replaceAll(regex, "somevalue$1");` to get `somevalue/something`. Alternatively remove the last part that contains the capturing group from the regex and use `original.replaceAll(regex,"somevalue")`.